# Bootstrap 4 Navbar overlapping with content on apple mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 website (https://sedomadrid2021.com) which has a navbar, the navbar has an odd issue on apple mobile devices: On the home page the navbar does not seem able to push all the content down and some of the menu gets overlapped by the content placed below, on the "ponentes" page, the content just doesn't get pushed down.

This is my home html:

```
<body>
<div class="outer">
<nav class="navegacion navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com">
    <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="110px">
    </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com/ponentes">Ponentes<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com/CartaSEDO.pdf">Inf&oacute;rmate</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btninscrib" href="https://atlanta.eventszone.net/myCongress/form.php?thisFormCongress=sedo21&thisFormLanguage=es">Inscr&iacute;bete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="contenedor-principal">
    <div class="contenedor-texto-principal">
        <span class="texto-titulo-principal">
            ¿Te lo vas<br>a perder?<br>
        </span>
        <span class="texto-parrafo-principal">
            <br>El 67º congreso de la sedo 2021 en Madrid congregará a los mejores profesionales de la ortodoncia de España en un evento de reencuentro cooperación y conocimiento
        </span>
    </div>
<div class="contenedor-bocadillo">
    <img class="fondo-bocadillo" src="/img/bocadillo.png" alt="fondo-texto">
    <span class="texto-bocadillo">Que no te<br>lo cuenten</span>
</div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

this is my "ponentes" page html:

```
<body>
<div class="outer">
<nav class="navegacion navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com">
    <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="110px">
    </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com/ponentes">Ponentes<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btnreg" href="https://sedomadrid2021.com/CartaSEDO.pdf">Inf&oacute;rmate</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mr-5 ml-5">
        <a class="nav-link btninscrib" href="https://atlanta.eventszone.net/myCongress/form.php?thisFormCongress=sedo21&thisFormLanguage=es">Inscr&iacute;bete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="contenedor-ponentes">
    <div class="titulo-precongreso">
    <h2>Precongreso</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="imgponente" src="/img/ponentes/pre-ewaczochrowska.jpg" alt="Ewa Czochrowska">
        <h4>Ewa Czochrowska</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="imgponente" src="/img/ponentes/pre-rafiromano.jpeg" alt="Rafi Romano">
        <h4>Rafi Romano</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titulo-congreso">
    <h2>Congreso</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row fila1congreso">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/wassimbouzid.jpeg" alt="Wassim Bouzid">
        <h4>Wassim Bouzid</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/luiscarriere.jpeg" alt="Luis Carriere">
        <h4>Luis Carriere</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/tommasocastroflorio.jpeg" alt="Tomasso Castroflorio">
        <h4>Tomasso Castroflorio</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row fila2congreso">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/alvaroferrando.jpeg" alt="Alvaro Ferrando">
        <h4>Álvaro Ferrando</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/raulferrando.jpeg" alt="Raul Ferrando">
        <h4>Raúl Ferrando</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/alejandroramirez.jpeg" alt="Alejandro Ramirez">
        <h4>Alejandro Ramírez</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row fila2congreso">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/pabloramirez.jpeg" alt="Pablo Ramirez">
        <h4>Pablo Ramirez</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/jeanlouisraymond.jpeg" alt="Jean Louis Raymond">
        <h4>Jean Louis Raymond</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="imgponente-cong" src="/img/ponentes/arturovela.jpeg" alt="Arturo Vela">
        <h4>Arturo Vela</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is my CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Rotunda-Regular";
  src: url(fonts/RotundaRegular.otf) format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic;
  src: url(fonts/RotundaExtraBoldItalic.otf) format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Rotunda-Light;
  src: url(fonts/RotundaLight.otf) format("opentype");
}

body{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.outer{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.navegacion{
    margin-right: 8%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navegacion li{
    font-family: "Rotunda-Regular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #141b4d;
    font-size: 1.35em;
}

.contenedor-principal{
    flex-grow : 1;
    background-image: url(/img/fondo-lg.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.contenedor-texto-principal{
    position: absolute;
    left: 8%;
    width: 20%;
    top: 30%;
}

.texto-titulo-principal{
    font-family: "Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic";
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    color: #f2827f;
}

.texto-parrafo-principal{
    font-family: "Rotunda-Light";
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #666666;
}

.fondo-bocadillo{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
    height: 250px;
}

.contenedor-bocadillo{
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    left: 70%;
    top: 65%;
}

.texto-bocadillo{
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffc845;
    font-family: "Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic";
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10002;
}


.btninscrib{
    font-family: "Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic";
    color: #f2827f !important;
    background-color: #7248bd;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px !important;;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
}

.btnreg{
    padding-top: 20px !important;
}


.contenedor-ponentes{
    margin-right: 7%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 5%; 
    
    text-align: center;
}

.imgponente{
    width: 55%;
}

.titulo-precongreso{
    color: #f2827f;
    font-family: "Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic";
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.titulo-precongreso h2{
    font-size: 3em !important;  
}

.titulo-congreso{
    color: #34a798;
    font-family: "Rotunda-ExtraBoldItalic";
    padding-top: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.titulo-congreso h2{
    font-size: 3em !important;  
}

.imgponente-cong{
    width: 60%;
}

.fila2congreso{
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.contenedor-ponentes h4{
    font-family: "Rotunda-Regular";
    padding-top: 5%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .contenedor-ponentes{
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .contenedor-principal{
        background-image: url(/img/fondo-sm.png);
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .contenedor-texto-principal{
        position:relative;
        width: 80%;
        left: 8%;
        top: 20%;   
    }
    
    .contenedor-bocadillo{
        width: 80%;
        left: 3%;
        top: 120%;
    }
    
    .fondo-bocadillo{
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

As I've mentioned, this issue is only happening on mobile apple devices. On android phones, windows desktops and apple desktops, everything is looking fine. This is a very simple webpage, you are able to navigate and visit the site directly if you want to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quick reply before looking into it more: this issue is also happening on Windows 10 using latest Firefox by just resizing the browser window. So it is not a Apple mobile issue only.

**Possible fix:**

So what I can see is that you are using `position: absolute` quite a lot on the main page. This seems to be breaking the dropdown menu (for good reasons).
Maybe change those to something else, because the absolute is what it says: absolute. Meaning it will stay where it is, no matter what happens around it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found the solution, the nav must be on the head of the page for some reason.

Comment: I'm sorry but the head is only for meta data, stylesheets, scripts and such. Anything rendered should be in the body tag. Your solution might work in your specific browser, but will likely break in other browsers or after a update.

Comment: You're right... I'm trying to find out why is it working when I place it out of the body tags...

Comment: Yea, I'm using position absolute to achieve some design features, however there isn't any of that interfering with the navbar as the absolute elements aren't close to the navbar itself. The issue was that the navbar was placed inside a "flex" div which broke it.

Comment: Did you update the website at the URL provided? Because for me it is still broken. Mind you I'm using a laptop screen with 1920x1080 resolution and zoomed by 125% by Windows, so my effective viewport height wise is less than 864px (and so those absolute div's are in fact very close and overlapping the navbar).

Comment: I'm doing some work with the flexbox, give me a minute. I'll be back asap.

Comment: Hello again, would you mind checking the issue on a private nav page ? Just to make sure cache doesn't interfere

Comment: I just checked and it's working now (private window and cache refresh both work). I also noticed you changed to ```position: relative``` now, which in my opinion is better anyway. If you need help again, let me know. But I'm confident you are on the right track now.

Comment: Yes, I went for relative following your advice, it's better for the responsiveness, you were right! Glad to hear everything is also ok for u. Issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

solution: The issue was because I was placing the navbar inside the "outer" div which is a flex div.